# Multiple cases statement IDs as a group by in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure to be used in an app. I need to be able to send multiple IDs to the stored procedure which will be associated to group bys.

Here is a sample of how my stored procedure should look like.

```
Declare @SQLGroupBy nvarchar(Max) = ' ';
Declare @GroupBy nvarchar(MAX) = ' '; 

Select @SQLGroupBy = case 
                         when @Groupby = 1 Then 'Employee_Name'
                         when @Groupby = 2 Then 'date'
                         when @Groupby = 3 Then 'Occupation'
                         when @Groupby = 4 Then 'Area'
                         when @Groupby = 5 Then 'Phone'
                         else ''
                     end

declare @sql nvarchar(max) ;

set @sql = 'select top 20 ' + @sqlGroupBy +
           ',count(*) as number
            from employee_table
            group by ' + @sqlGroupBy + 
           'order by count(*) desc;';
```

I need to be able to send multiple IDs related to the group by to the stored procedure as shown here:

```
exec [Proc_Name] '1,5'
```

and get the corresponding value into my group by

Thank you

I was able to send only one ID and the procedure works fine, but when I run this

```
exec [Proc_Name] '1,5'
```

I got this error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,5' to data type int

I don't want to convert I need to send to the procedure the value corresponding to ID 1 and 5 together.

Comment: Missing the SP declaration but I suppose the param `GroupBy` is of type `int`.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest) to split your input string and [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to combine your columns for grouping e.g.

```
declare @SQLGroupBy nvarchar(max) = '';

select 
    @SQLGroupBy = string_agg(case 
        when value = 1 Then 'Employee_Name'
        when value = 2 Then 'date'
        when value = 3 Then 'Occupation'
        when value = 4 Then 'Area'
        when value = 5 Then 'Phone'
        else ''
    end, ', ')
from string_split(@GroupBy,',');

declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = 'select top 20 '
+ @sqlGroupBy
+ ', count(*) as number'
+ ' from employee_table'
+ ' group by '
+ @sqlGroupBy 
+ ' order by count(*) desc;';

select @sql;
```

Comment: Thank you so much I did use split and string aggregate but wasn't sure where to put it

Comment: I had another question, I followed your code and it works perfectly , now I need to save the input into two variables and check if the user sent both variables then count the number of occurrence of each variable. The user must at least choose one variable and s/he can choose multiple , I used the build in ParseName function it works fine if I have two selection but when only one is selected the function doesn't work